# What do the percentages refer to in this sentence?

Tags: traduction

I'm not sure if the percentages here are referring to the percentage of businesses i.e 80% of businesses surveyed said the main cause was loss of opportunities, compared to 77% in July.. or does it mean there has been an 80% loss of opportunities?

> Les entreprises qui demeurent concernées par une chute d’activité font face à un choc de
> demande. Les causes évoquées de réduction d'activité sont avant tout la perte de débouchés
> (80 % après 77 % en juillet), plutôt que les fermetures administratives (9 % après 12 % en
> juillet), le manque de personnel pouvant travailler (5 %, comme en juillet) ou les difficultés
> d'approvisionnement (7 % après 6 % en juillet).

Source: [Activité et conditions d’emploi de la main-d’œuvre pendant la crise sanitaire Covid-19 - septembre 2020](https://dares.travail-emploi.gouv.fr/dares-etudes-et-statistiques/tableaux-de-bord/le-marche-du-travail-pendant-le-covid-19/enquete-acemo-pendant-la-crise-sanitaire-covid-19/article/activite-et-conditions-d-emploi-de-la-main-d-oeuvre-pendant-la-crise-sanitaire-119550)

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is close to the first one:

> 80% of businesses surveyed said the main cause was loss of opportunities

If you look to the [full report](https://dares.travail-emploi.gouv.fr/IMG/pdf/dares_acemo_covid_synthese_septembre_2020.pdf), you can see that it is not a percentage of businesses but a percentage of the total number of employees:

> Note de lecture : 80 % des salariés travaillent dans une entreprise où l'activité a diminué en août du fait d’une perte de débouchés.